# Enable seeing the PHP source code of my test files from web browser

Tags: apache-2.2, php, documentation, source

I would like to make my UnitTests available to see via the browser.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
application
docs
public
 - index.php
tests
```

My DocumentRoot is in the public folder. However, when I try to add an alias /source to my Apache configuration and set add the type php-source to the .php files (instead of just .phps) Apache still tries to execute the files.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found:

```
Alias /test "/var/www/api_dev/tests"
<Directory "/var/www/api_dev/tests/">
     AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, is simply rename/copy the file to a .phps extension.

The MIME type should already be in place and you should be ready to go.

- Mime:text/html
- Mime:application/x-httpd-php-source
- Mime:application/x-httpd-php3-source

Comment: The problem with this is: I want the visitor to see my Unit tests that I also run to check my code. So I can't just rename the files to .phps.